# i get an empty list when scraping a website

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = requests.get("https://www.upwork.com/nx/jobs/search/?q=web%20scraping&sort=recency")
source = link.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

title = soup.find_all("h4", {"class": "my-0 p-sm-right job-tile-title"})
print(title)
```

i am trying to scrap the job titles but the problem is that i get an empty list
but in other websites it work just fine

help me please

Comment: You can't scrape this website using request because content are generated dynamically and not statically!

Comment: you can use selenium to scrape the website, let me know if you need help in doing that

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar i really appreciate your help... i think i am gonna start learning about selenium and if i face any problem i'll let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got an empty list because this data loads from a different request. You can see it if opens the console in your browser, network tab

[Needed request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHe5N.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).